# Keeping 2 nav menu's in sync in a SPA site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

First off, I am primarily a back end developer.

Building a site with 2 navs. Main nav with something like home ect and a sub nav with about us, contact us ect..

The nav changes enough between the bootstrap XS view and the regular view that it needs 2 completely different menus code wise. I want to keep them in sync so if someone clicks on a sub nav in >xs and then re-sizes to xs, the correct nav is still highlighted. Or vise versa.

Ie the home nav has 4 sub navs in >xs, but in xs it turns into a drop down menu and has 6 sub navs. So some custom logic will be needed either way.

My thought was to use the hash in the url to keep track of what nav/subnav is current. When the nav in xs is expanded, read the hash url and change what is highlighted/expanded. Since clicking anywhere will collapse any sub nav drop down, I don't see any way other than to expand/highlight what is current when expanding the sub nav.

So simply, what is the best way to handle this? I am used to using backbone for my spa sites and I don't think it can handle this, I can also think of many ways to do this through just JS, or maybe angular has a good way to deal with it.

Built many spa sites with backbone as I normally just need the navigation so angular seems like a bit of overkill, but I've never dealt with angular in depth and maybe it will do better at handling this.

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Hope it all makes sense.

I know it's a lot, but thanx ahead of time. Hope it makes sense.

Some of the code as requested:
    
        
            
            
                
                    Toggle navigation

```
            <div class="navbar-left visible-xs LogoLarge" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 1px; text-align: center; margin-left: 87px;">
                <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/Logo.gif" height="45" /></a>
                <div class="" style="float: right; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 16px; ">
                    <a class="btn" href="#" style="">
                        <i class="icon-shopping-cart-white" style=""></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-left visible-sm LogoSm" style="padding-top: 0; margin-top: 5px;"><a href="#about"><img src="~/Images/Logo007700.jpg" height="40" /></a></div>
            <div class="navbar-left hidden-sm hidden-xs LogoLarge" style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 15px;"><a href="#about"><img src="~/Images/Logo007700.jpg" height="50" /></a></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Expanded Main Menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbar-main-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="">
                <li class="active" style=""><a href="#Home" id="HomeNav" onclick="ChangeTab(this)" data-toggle="tab"><span>H</span>OME</a></li>
                <li style=""><a href="#Wiki" id="WikiNav" onclick="ChangeTab(this)" data-toggle="tab"><span>W</span>IKI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#MySetup" id="MySetupNav" onclick="ChangeTab(this)" data-toggle="tab"><span>M</span>Y <span>S</span>ETUP</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#Store" id="StoreNav" onclick="ChangeTab(this)" data-toggle="tab"><span>S</span>TORE</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navbar-right hidden-xs" style="margin-top: 3px;">
                <div>
                    <a class="btn" href="#" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-right: -1px; padding: 0; ">
                        <i class="icon-profile-dark" style=""></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="account" style=""><span>A</span>CCOUNT</a>
                    <a class="btn" href="#" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 16px; ">
                        <i class="icon-shopping-cart-dark" style=""></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Secondary Expanded Menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse second-menu" id="navbar-sub-collapse" style="">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SecondaryMenu.cshtml")
        </div>


        <!--Collapsed Slide Menu -->
        <div class="navbar-default side-collapse in visible-xs slide-menu" style="" id="slideMenu">
            <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-collapse" style="padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 0; ">
                    <!--Home Drop down-->
                    <li class="dropdown navSlide">
                        <a href="#Home" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="HomeNavSlide" name="HomeNavSlide" onclick="ChangeTab(this)" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span>H</span>OME<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="xxxy">
                            <li class="active" style=""><a href="#About" data-toggle="tab" data-target="HomeNav">About</a></li>
                            <li style=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">News</a></li>
                            <li style=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Mission</a></li>
                            <li style=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" id="HomeSlideForums" data-target="#HomeForums">Forums</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <!--Wiki Drop Down-->
                    <li class="dropdown navSlide">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="WikiNavSlide" onclick="ChangeTab(this)" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span>W</span>IKI<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="WikiNavSub">
                            <li class="active" style=""><a href="#About" data-toggle="tab" id="Wikia">A</a></li>
                            <li class="" style=""><a href="#About" data-toggle="tab" id="Wikib">B</a></li>
                            <li class="" style=""><a href="#About" data-toggle="tab" id="WikiC">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-side]');
            var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');

            sideslider.click(function (event) {
                $(sel).toggleClass('in');
                $("#HomeNavSlide").dropdown('toggle');
            });

Comment: can you post some of your navbar markup?

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow messed up some of the code, but the basics seem to be there. .

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a great thing about angularjs, since you have two way data binding the only thing necessary to keep the states in sync is to use the same scope variable. For example:

```
<div class="navbar1">
  <div ng-class="{'active': vm.foo}">Large item</div>
</div>

<div class="navbar2">
  <div ng-class="{'active': vm.foo}">Small Item</div>
</div>
```

Both the large and small version of the item have the 'active' class, since they are both tied into the same variable.

#### edit:

oh I see, you're not binding to a model or using angular anywhere in the navbar code. It's not so easy to maintain consistent states between two different versions of a menu when you don't have any programmatic access to their state. You might change that. I'd recommend tapping into ui-bootstrap's `on-toggle(open)` to set the open/close state of a boolean, and then use that on both instance of each menu item by adding the `open` class like `<div ng-class="{'open':aboutUsMenuOpen}">`

Comment: Somewhat ignorant on Angular sorry. If I am understanding you right, because I can modelbind 2 objects to the same function, it makes things a little cleaner? I wonder if the extra overhead is the angular.js files is worth it, but again, don't understand angular in detail.